# Javascript y Jquery no cambian el css (left y top)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Tengo un código donde al pasar el cursor por un *div*, coloca `"display: block"` en otro div y lo posiciona según el *div* donde se pasó el cursor (de manera que el *div* que estaba invisible quede justo al lado del *div* donde tengo el cursor), pero cuando intento llevarlo a la práctica las propiedades **top** y **left** no se ejecutan. El *div* tiene de estilo **posicion absolute** e intenté con `.style.top`  y con `.css("left",valor+"%)`, pero no funciona ninguno de los dos.

```
$("#informacion").html(res);
$("#informacion").css("display", "block");
if (parseInt(numero) <= 5) {
  document.getElementById("informacion").style.top = (11.5 * parseInt(numero)) + "%";
} else {
  if (parseInt(numero) % 1 != 0) {
    document.getElementById("informacion").style.top = (11.5 + (22.3 *
      (Math.round(parseInt(numero))))) + "%";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("informacion").style.top = (11.5 * parseInt(numero)) + "%";
  }
  document.getElementById("informacion").style.left = (11.5 * (parseInt(numero) -
    (5 * Math.round(parseInt(numero))))) + "%";
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la razón de usar jquery y javascript en el mismo código? ¿cómo que hay veces que usas $() y a veces document. para acceder a lo mismo? te sugiero que uses $().css() para cambiar estilos ya que usas jquery y si falla, puede que sea porque otra regla css con prioridad no te deja, entonces arregla eso o usa !important.

Comment: como dije probe ambos el style.top y el css(), si en este codigo hay js y jquery fue porque antes de publicar la pregunta quise intentar con el style de js

Comment: ok, prueba a usar !important en la regla css a ver qué tal.

Comment: pero, tengo una duda como le añado el important? solo despues del % en el codigo js?

Comment: Estas seguro que obtienes un valor correcto de la variable `numero`?

Comment: En tu código de ejemplo no se aprecia lo que es `res` ni lo que es `numero`.  Por favor, incluyelo correctamente para formar un [example] que podamos replicar y darte una respuesta.  Recuerda incluir también el HTML correspondiente a todo lo que pongas, gracias.

Comment: Aparte de eso, diría que tienes un fallo cuando calculas el `left`, pues siempre da negativo y se sale de la pantalla. Has puesto esto como fórmula: `(11.5 * (parseInt(numero) - (5 * Math.round(parseInt(numero)))))`, es decir, multiplicas 11,5 por el resultado de esto: `(parseInt(numero) - (5 * Math.round(parseInt(numero))))`, cuando seguramente lo que quieres es esto: `(11.5 * parseInt(numero) - (5 * Math.round(parseInt(numero))))`. En [este enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/ab8tpezr/) verás que a mi me funciona todo (o no, porque queda fuera de la pantalla, pero modifícalo y dale al run de nuevo)

Comment: Y además `parseInt(numero) % 1` siempre es 0, ¿no? Un número entero siempre da resto 0 al dividirlo por 1

Comment: el valor de numero lo probe con un alert solo, con parseInt y con la formula a ver si lo mostraba correctamente y si funciona de todas formas probare de la marea que me dices y compruebo si me da negativo

Comment: Muchas gracias por resaltarmelo, habia errores matematicos, y note que la formula del left era diferente cuando es el valor menor o igual a 5

Comment: dices: ¿como le añado el important?  si, detrás del %, un ejemplo sería "% !important"